# short duration of crew 4 mission

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight

I am wondering why the crew 4 mission is (for the moment) only planned for 4 and half months and not the usual  6-6.5 months? Thanks.

Comment: Where did you see 4 1/2 months [NASA’s SpaceX
Crew-4](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/crew-4_mission_overview.pdf) has it as "Crew-4 is scheduled for a long duration stay of up to six months aboard station conducting science and maintenance before returning to Earth in the fall of 2022."

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome implicitely on https://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Human_and_Robotic_Exploration/Revised_flight_plan_brings_change_for_Samantha or the German entry on wikipedia for crew 4 etc